# jQuery live not firing on resize and scroll

Tags: jquery

Can someone let me know why the following code isn't firing the `console.log` on `resize` and `scroll`? (jquery 1.7 is definitely loaded).

```
<script>
$(window).live('scroll resize', function ()
{
    console.log('am i working?');
}); 
</script>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`live` is deprecated in jQuery 1.7 and above.

```
As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.
```

**[check Documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/live/)**. Instead make use of `.on()` **[on documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/)**

Comment: That only works for window, not something like: $(window).on('scroll', 'div', function () { ... });